# how is a rosconsole message making it to /rosout?

Tags: ros, c++, rosout, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been reading the rosconsole code and I can't find any publisher to /rosout. rosconsole dependencies are only rostime, cpp_common, rostime and console_bridge. Can someone explain exactly how those work?

I see that rosconsole is a wrapper around log4cxx. It handles the initialization, provides vargs interface, formatting and the logging macros.
I am confused about what console bridge is supposed to do.
There is also the rosout package that dumps the messages on the /rosout topic to a file (which seems redundant to what rosconsole is doing...)

But I can't find a publisher from rosconsole to /rosout

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230760/how-is-a-rosconsole-message-making-it-to-/rosout?/) by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1001 on 2016-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out that ros::init in roscpp sets the global logger object to be a ROSOutAppender which publishes to /rosout.

---

Originally posted by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) with karma: 1001 on 2016-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1